# how to avoid timeouts with remote API requests?

Tags: rest-api, wp-remote-request

I'm developing a plugin, [WP SoundSystem](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-soundsystem/), that makes [Wordpress rest requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to my remote API api.spiff-radio.org.

That API is scraping content on the web.
Which means that it might be slow to get the data.
(EDIT:that data is just plain text tracklists)

So

1. WP SoundSystem plugin requests data on api.spiff-radio.org...
2. ...api.spiff-radio.org scrapes the web...
3. ...api.spiff-radio.org returns a response...
4. ...WP SoundSystem plugin gets the response

WHICH might be quite slow.  I already set a 20 seconds timeout ([default is 5](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Http/request/)) when querying the API with [wp_remote_request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/).
But still, I often get a timeout error.

Since I don't know if the API request will require 5 or 150 seconds, is there a way to disable timeouts for this particular request ?  Or should I just set a very large timeout ?

How would you handle this ?

Thanks.

Comment: do you ask for requests made by the plugin ? or by the server api.spiff-radio.org ? do you get streams or only music files ?

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt, but this sounds horrible. You're using PHP, which means your process is synchronous and blocks because it waits for the API result. I take it you control the API, so I would start here. Either [use a queue approach](https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs/), or you could do it similar as "return urls" work for payments: In you initial request to the API, supply a `finishedRoute`. Then your API calls that finishedRoute once it found a result - each request is now a fast one

Comment: I just get plain text tracklists (artists & track titles).
I don't see how to do otherwise.  There is a loader spinning frontend while the tracklist is reloading (try the "refresh bt here:https://www.spiff-radio.org/?p=80).  How could I handle this faster ?

Comment: You can't make it faster just put the timeout to something huge if you don't wanna implement webhooks and queues.